# How to access a scope from a directive in-another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some help in understanding how I can access `$scope.imageUpload.image_file` within my firstCtr controller.

I have the following markup:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="firstCtr">
 <div image-upload></div>
</div>
```

The imageload directive creates a new scope called `$scope.imageUpload.image_file` which works fine.

```
   .directive('imageUpload', function () {
    // Directive used to display a badge.
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "/static/html/partials/directives/imageToolsUpload.html",
        controller: function ($scope) {
           $scope.onImageSelect = function ($files) {
               console.log( $scope.project);
                $scope.imageUpload = {};
                $scope.imageUpload.image_file =  $files[0];
        };
        }
    }
});
```

However, when I then try to get the scope $scope.imageUpload.image_file within firstCtr it is undefined.

```
 .controller("firstCtr", ['$scope', '$rootScope', "$location", etc.....

           $scope.actionClick = function () {
                 console.log($scope.imageUpload)
            }
```

I can do this using rootscope but thats seems like a bad idea. Is there a better way to pass this scope back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

One way is in your imageUpload directive, inject a property in the parent scope, so that the controller of that parent scope can then access it and do what it has to do with it. So in your imageUpload directive controller function:

```
$scope.$parent.imageUpload = {};
$scope.$parent.image_File = $files[0];
```

For a more robust solution, I would probably go with using the `require` keyword in your imageUpload directive, so it can reliably access to firstCtr controller and set properties in it.

```
.directive('imageUpload', function () {
    // Directive used to display a badge.
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'firstCtr'
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "/static/html/partials/directives/imageToolsUpload.html",
        controller: function ($scope, element, attrs, firstCtr) {
           $scope.onImageSelect = function ($files) {
               console.log( $scope.project);
               firstCtr.imageUpload = {};
               firstCtr.imageUpload.image_file =  $files[0];
        };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: so how do you pass in a controller? Can it be any controller?

Comment: By specifying require: 'firstCtr' in your directive, angularjs looks for a matching directive and returns you in parameter the controller of that directive, if there is one. See AngularJS documentation here to understand how a directive can require another directive and get access to its controller among the ones on the same HTMLElement, or a parent HTMLElement: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. The page contains a lot of stuff, but this is the most important page of all AngularJS documentation. It's a must read.